# Spring "hello world" example error: A JNI error has occured & NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I tried to use Eclipse to run the Spring Framework "Quick Start" tutorial at 
http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

I firstly built a Maven Project in Eclipse, and added three .java files.
The codes are as follows

```
package hello;

public interface MessageService {
    String getMessage();
}
```

---

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessagePrinter {

    final private MessageService service;

    @Autowired
    public MessagePrinter(MessageService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void printMessage(){
        System.out.println(this.service.getMessage());
    }

}
```

---

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService(){
        return new MessageService(){
            public String getMessage() {
                return "Hello World!";
            }};
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ApplicationContext context = 
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
        printer.printMessage();
    }

}
```

Then I right clicked the Eclipse and choose "run as > Java Application". Two error messages jumped out:

1. Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again
2. A Java Exception has occurred.

and the console showed

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more

**I have tried to add more Spring dependencies (including aop aspects beans context context-support core ...) in the POM file, but that didn't work.**

Comment: try adding the `spring-beans` dependency to your `pom`

Comment: I have tried to add Spring dependencies (including aop aspects beans context context-support core ...) in the POM file, but that didn't work.

Comment: Since you are using Eclipse to run the app, you would need to add the corresponding jar file to the project build path. Right click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add external Jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already fixed this problem. In fact this problem had little relationship to "A JNI error has occured".

The cause of the this problem is that **an error(s) occured when Eclipse download Maven dependency jar file**, namely "spring-beans".

So I (manually) deleted all the files in "....m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans", and used Eclipse to rebuild the project. In this way the problem was fixed.

Comment: In fact, this example "hello world" program does not need to add dependencies of spring-beans, etc in the POM file. Only "spring-context" is  necessary